# Image quality loss when reassigning image to UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, image-size, image-quality

I am developing an application which can tint colors in an image and export it.

I have added 3 versions of an image asset to my Assets.xcassets folder.
These are 3 different sizes of the same image, namely:
image1.png image1@2x.png image1@3x.png
with respective sizes: 256x341, 512x683, 768x1024 pixels.

I have created a `UIImageView` on my storyboard called myImage and assigned image1 to myImage via storyboard->utilities->attributes inspector-> Image View -> Image.

I am trying to use the following `tintWithColor` function as a `UIImage` extension to change the color of this image.

```
 extension UIImage {

    func tintWithColor(color:UIColor)->UIImage {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        self.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        CGContextSaveGState(context)

        // flip the image
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -self.size.height)

        // multiply blend mode
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Multiply)

        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)
        color.setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)

        // create uiimage
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage   
    }
}
```

As I am testing this function on my `viewDidLoad()` to change the color of `myImage.image` as below, I see that (on whatever device I am using) the width and height of my `originalImage` is always 256 x 341,5

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let originalImage =  myImage.image
    print("LOG: original image width: \(originalImage!.size.width) height: \(originalImage!.size.height)")
    let tintedImage = originalImage!.tintWithColor(UIColor(hue: 300/360, saturation: 0.70, brightness: 0.70, alpha: 0.6))
     myImage.image = tintedImage
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

If I don't apply these changes on my image, the quality of my image on an iPhone 6 (4,7") device looks as below:

[image]

If I apply the `tintWithColor` and then reassign the resulting image to my `imageView` the quality seems to drop, lines smoothen, as can be seen below:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this quality loss?
Eventually I will be exporting the high quality image, so I would like to apply this color tint function on the high quality version of this image.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to create a context at screen scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height), false, 3.0)

should work

Comment: It works. But now whichever device I am using it won't matter, the 3x version of the image will be loaded after a change in the color, am I right?

Comment: No I don't think so, the image being loaded is based on the device, the 3x version will only be loaded on the 6 plus.